# How to handle reset-password request after it use/expire

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a reset password function on my site, and it is working pretty good. But I am a little uncertain at some points.

Right now I have a table like this:

**password_change_request:**

```
ID    |     user_id       |       token       |      created_time
```

In the **user_id**-field the users username will be stored. In the **token** -field, the genereted and encrypted token will be stored. And finally in the **created_time**, the timestamp for the request time will be stored.

---

### **Make the request:**

When users enteres their email in the **Forgot Password** form, the system will look up in the **users**-table to check if the user exist. If the user do exist, it will find the users username.

It will also generate a token by encrypting the users email along with a random SALT.

Then it will send a link with the username and token to the entered email-address, like this: http://yoursite.com/login.php?action=reset&token=28130dh29sd129809sda802e&user=yourusername

The token will be extra encrypted when it is stored in the database.

### **Reset password:**

When the user has clicked on the link, in the email, it will lead the user to a site that will check if there exist any request in the **password_change_request**-table, with the given username and encrypted token.

If it does, it will check if the request is over 2 hours old by calculating the difference between the **created_time** in the database and the current time.

If it is not over 2 hours old, two fields will appear, where the user can enter a new password, and then reenter it for security reasons.

When the user has entered a new password and then hit on the "Reset" button, a new SALT for the user will be generated and the new password, encrypted with the salt, will be updated in the **users**-table.

When the new password has been updated and if the request is over 2 hours old, the request will be deleted in from the **password_change_request**-table.

---

Is this a good way to do it? It has been inspired by WordPress and other answers on this site.

But one thing I could find was what would happen to the request when it has been used/expired?

Should it just be deleted permanently from the database? I cannot seem to find another way to do so. Without this feature, the user could just be reusing the link, again and again.

So beside if it is a good way or not, the main question is how to handle the requests after they have been used or expired?

Or should I just put the token in a column of the **users**-table, like WordPress do, and then just clear the field, when request has been used/expired?

Hope someone can help me :)

- TheYaXxE

Comment: After the new password is set, why would you only delete the request when it is over two hours old? (And how is that even supposed to work, if _changing_ the password is only possible if it is _not_ more than two hours old yet?) If the user successfully set a new password – then delete the record, it is not needed any more. And if the user requests a password change after the two hours have passed – then send a new link via email, and either update the existing record, or delete it and create a new one.

Comment: And if you want to “purge” expired records regularly, either use a cronjob, or do that every time a password request is made/a new password is set. (Both should not happen that often, so that just issuing a `DELETE … WHERE older_than_x` statement every time should not harm performance noticeably. Timestamp column should be indexed.)

Comment: I also have seen somewhere, where the token are stored along with the user, in the users table. So instead off having a new table for password-request, the token are stored in a token-key column at the user. Is this a better way? I see WordPress are using it

Comment: Neither of those is necessarily “better” than the other. Question: Is this something that will happen for _all_ users? No, it will of course not, it can rather be expected that only a minority will use it. So does it make sense to have that column in the general user data table? Maybe not so much.

Comment: And, if you were to include the timestamp in the token _and_ also send it as unencrypted value withing the same link, then you could verify it nonetheless, and there would not even be any need to store it into the database in the first place. (Although you might want to store it, if you think you might need records of when/how many times a user requested a new password, to detect fraudulent requests. But that would mean deleting those records after time or when a new password has been set would be counter-productive.)

Answer (score 1):

See how Laravel Framework does it from the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/security#password-reminders-and-reset).

The source can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Reminders).

Basically it asks the user for an email sends a link to a password reset with hash binded to the email. Hash is validated then a new password and a new password confirmation is asked.

You can learn more by checking the source I linked to on [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/).

```
// Create a new reminder record and token.
public function create(RemindableInterface $user)
{
    $email = $user->getReminderEmail();

    // We will create a new, random token for the user so that we can e-mail them
    // a safe link to the password reset form. Then we will insert a record in
    // the database so that we can verify the token within the actual reset.
    $token = $this->createNewToken($user);

    $this->getTable()->insert($this->getPayload($email, $token));

    return $token;
}

// Create a new token for the user.
public function createNewToken(RemindableInterface $user)
{
    $email = $user->getReminderEmail();

    $value = str_shuffle(sha1($email.spl_object_hash($this).microtime(true)));

    return hash_hmac('sha1', $value, $this->hashKey);
}

// Determine if the reminder has expired.
protected function reminderExpired($reminder)
{
    $createdPlusHour = strtotime($reminder->created_at) + $this->expires;

    return $createdPlusHour < $this->getCurrentTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to rather include the time in the hash. Then you can extract the time difference when the user come in through the link with the hash.
You can also clear the hash field after use.
In that way, you will be able to specifically inform the user if the link has expired, or invalid, or if no pending request has been made at all.

Comment: Why is it better to put the created-time in the token, and how to a calculate the time difference, if the created-time is encrypted along with the token?

And instead of deleting the entire request row, I should only clear the token field?

Comment: Obviously you would have to pass the timestamp un-hashed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah since you are using a dedicated table for this task, it's advisable to simple delete the used row entirely; why keeping it?

Secondly, you can decrypt the hash to extract the time since it will be in the same order as when you encrypt it.

```
   $difference=time()-$extractedTime;       //kindof
   $hoursDifference=ceil($difference/7200); //2*60*60=7200
```

if this is helpful please take a moment to vote it, Thanks.